# Reactjs component showing old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that is supposed to show a list of items. The items are fetched from an API when the component first is loaded, and then the items should be refreshed/replaced when the user clicks a button.

The problem is, my component always seems to be one step behind the user. For example, the first time the user clicks the button the API is called and returns new data, but the component still shows the data it got on initial load. The second time the user clicks, my component shows the data that was returned on the first click.

I'm thinking that the component is reloaded to quick after the button click, so the state isn't updated when the component is displayed, but I have no idea how to solve it?

My component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {matchesFetchData} from '../actions/matches';
import Match from './match';


class MatchList extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.generateNew = this.generateNew.bind(this);
    }  

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('http://localhost:4752/api/matches');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry!There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }

        return (   
            <div>
                <nav className="menu">
                    <input type="number" defaultValue="0" min="0" max="13" ref="safeguards"/>      
                    <button className="generateNew" onClick={this.generateNew}>Ny</button>         
                </nav>
                <ul className="matchlist">
                    {this.props.matches.map(function (match, index) {                        
                        return <Match key={index} match={match}/>
                    }) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    generateNew(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const value = this.refs.safeguards.value;
        if(value == 0){
            this.props.fetchData('http://localhost:4752/api/matches');
        }
        else{
            this.props.fetchData('http://localhost:4752/api/matches/' + value);
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        matches: state.matchesApp.matches,
        hasErrored: state.matchesApp.matchesHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.matchesApp.matchesIsLoading
    };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url) => dispatch(matchesFetchData(url))
    };
};  

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MatchList);
```

Actions:

```
export const MATCHES_HAS_ERRORED = 'MATCHES_HAS_ERRORED';
export const MATCHES_IS_LOADING = 'MATCHES_IS_LOADING';
export const MATCHES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'MATCHES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS';

export function matchesHasErrored(bool){
    return {
        type: MATCHES_HAS_ERRORED,
        hasErrored: bool
    };
}

export function matchesIsLoading(bool){
    return {
        type: MATCHES_IS_LOADING,
        isLoading: bool
    };
}

export function matchesFetchDataSuccess(matches){
    return{
        type: MATCHES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
        matches
    };
}

export function matchesFetchData(url){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(matchesIsLoading(true));

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok){
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            dispatch(matchesIsLoading(false));

            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((matches) => dispatch(matchesFetchDataSuccess(matches)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(matchesHasErrored(true)));
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import {MATCHES_HAS_ERRORED, MATCHES_IS_LOADING, MATCHES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS} from '../actions/matches';

const initialState = {
    matchesIsLoading: false,
    matchesHasErrored: false,
    matches: []
}

export function matchesApp(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
      case MATCHES_HAS_ERRORED:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                matchesHasErrored: action.hasErrored
            });
      case MATCHES_IS_LOADING:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                matchesIsLoading: action.isLoading
            });
      case MATCHES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                matchesIsLoading: false,
                matchesHasErrored: false,
                matches: action.matches
            });
      default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Match component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Result from './result';

class Match extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.match = this.props.match;
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <Link to={'/' + this.match.home + '/' + this.match.away}>
                    <span className="matchNumber">{this.match.number}</span>
                    <span className="matchup">
                        {this.match.home} - {this.match.away}
                    </span>
                    <Result value="1" selected={this.match.homeWin} odds={this.match.percent1}/><Result value="X" selected={this.match.draw} odds={this.match.percentX}/><Result value="2" selected={this.match.awayWin} odds={this.match.percent2}/>
                </Link>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default Match;
```

Comment: I looked your code over. Looks correct. Have you tried inspecting what happens the first time the button is clicked?

Comment: Also you can put log things in your reducer and actions to see if they are being called.

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu When I click the button, the reducer logs the new, correct data. The action also logs the new, correct data. But if I put a log in the render function of my component it logs twice, first the old data, then the new. But it's the old data that is displayed.

Comment: The second time the render call gets called did you try logging the value of the match data before returning your JSX?

Comment: I've put a console.log(this.props.matches) right before render(), aswell as inside the render function right before {this.props.matches.map()}. Both have the same result: two entries in the console, the first one with the old data and the second one with the new data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending upon what the  component looks like, it is possible that there is a problem with the key property that you are passing down, where if the display value of the  comes from state, the component will not be completely removed, and thus will display stale data

Comment: Please post the source of the <Match /> component

Comment: I've added the match component to the question.

Comment: Yep, sounds like you're not updating the `this.props` value ever, and since the key is not unique in the <Match /> components that you are rendering. If you make the <Match /> component's render function use this.props.match instead of this.match I think that will work. Alternatively, you could add a 
`
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  this.match = nextProps.match;
}
`
That will also work. The last solution would be to make sure that the key prop that you are passing down is unique to each <Match /> component that you render, across your entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this:

```
<ul className="matchlist">
  {this.props.matches.map(function (match, index) {                        
    return <Match key={index} match={match}/>
  }) }
</ul>
```

with this:

```
let matchesData = this.props.matches.map(function (match, index) {                        
  return <Match key={index} match={match}/>
}) ;

...
return(
  <div>
    <nav className="menu">
      <input type="number" defaultValue="0" min="0" max="13" ref="safeguards"/>      
      <button className="generateNew" onClick={this.generateNew}>Ny</button>         
    </nav>
    <ul className="matchlist">
      {matchesData}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but with the same results as before.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but can u get rid of e.preventDefault? If its a form replace it with a div.

Comment: Nope, made no difference. Appreciate you taking the time though :)